# Fixing case sensitive file names issues in different Git branches

Tags: git

I have multiple branches (master, developer and feature/*), and somehow file names were committed with differing cases.

In master and develop branches I have Assets.php and events.php which are correct (they're different vendor libraries hence the case difference). But in a feature branch the file names are currently assets.php and Events.php, the complete opposite casing. When I try to checkout a feature branch I get the following error.

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout: 
    assets.php
    Events.php
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

I managed to fix the issue between my master and develop branch through an unscientific series of deleting, committing, re-adding, and committing and I'd rather not repeat that process for my 3 other feature branches.

Since I can't even checkout my feature branch to pull in the changes from master/develop I'm unsure how to work around this without fumbling through a series of removing/adding/committing files on each branch.

What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to be on Windows (otherwise you wouldn't have this problem), I would assume that the config setting `core.ignorecase` is already enabled, but apparently it's not.

So what I would do:

- Enable `core.ignorecase` using `git config core.ignorecase true`
- Check out the feature branch (which should now work)
- Use `git mv` to fix the case of the filenames

(You should also be able to disable `core.ignorecase` again and the run `git status` to see if there is any mixup.)

If it doesn't work, maybe you need a newer version of Git. I tested this using version "2.8.1.windows.1".

The other solution not relying on `core.ignorecase` would be cloning the repo in a new folder, using the `-b` argument to specify the branch to check out upon cloning, and fixing things there. Since `git mv` won't work for something like `a.txt A.txt` if the `core.ignorecase` isn't set or isn't supported, you would need to do two moves: `git mv a.txt a2.txt` and `git mv a2.txt A.txt`.

Comment: I assumed I already had ignorecase set to true, but apparently did not and forgot to check it. Setting it to true did let me checkout the feature branch and fix the issue. Funny thing is, I'm on a Mac and everyone who has ever worked on this project before me is also on a Mac. Not sure why its suddenly an issue.

Comment: That's kinda weird, because I would assume you wouldn't have this issue on a Mac in the first place (it would just let you check out fine). Maybe you have the local repository stored on a case-insensitive filesystem, such as an USB stick formatted with FAT32, a Samba network share or anything like this?